# Error handling in batch script

Tags: batch-file, error-handling, runas

I have a batch file which contains below code:

```
runas /user:Administrator "C:\Test.bat"
```

When i'm running  this file it asks for Password so if in case i give incorrect password it directly terminates but i want to handle this error. It should not terminate directly.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it in a loop:

```
:loop
runas /user:Administrator "C:\Test.bat" || goto :loop
```

As long as `runas` fails (for example because of a wrong password), it will try again.